# How Can That Be Possible? ${i} = 1/(\sqrt{2i}+1)$

Tags: complex-numbers, radicals

If $ \sqrt{-i} = \frac {1-i} {\sqrt{2}} \land \sqrt{-i} = i\sqrt{i} \Rightarrow \frac {1-i} {\sqrt{2}} = i\sqrt{i}$

$$\Rightarrow {1-i} = {i}\sqrt{2i}$$

$$\Rightarrow {i}\sqrt{2i} +{i} =1$$

$$\Rightarrow {i}(\sqrt{2i}+1) =1 $$

$$\Rightarrow {1\over{i}} = \sqrt{2i}+1$$

$$\Rightarrow ({i} =  {1 \over \sqrt{2i}+1}) $$

How Can That Be Possible?

Comment: $\sqrt{-i} \ne i \sqrt{i}$.

Comment: $Why$ $not?$ $\sqrt{-i} = i\sqrt{i}$

Answer (score 3):

There's nothing wrong with that except you need to use a non-principal square root of $2i$.

The square roots of $2i$ are $1+i$ and $-1-i$. And indeed,
$$ i = \frac{1}{(-1-i)+1} $$

In general the rule $\sqrt a \sqrt b = \sqrt{ab}$ works for complex numbers only if you accept that one or more of the square roots may need to be non-principal.

Comment: $So,$ $\sqrt{2} = {1+{i}\over {\sqrt{i}}}?$